# Why does the inverse of ln lead to this expression?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, linear-regression

I have the following information available

[image: table]

The graph for a function that describes the relation between year (t) and ln(y) is shown here

[image: graph]

Based on the given data, a function has been derived using linear regression with the result that
$$
\text{ln }y \simeq 0.507t-983.054
$$

Now I have been told that based on this information, I should be able to describe $y = y(t)$ with the expression
$$y = y(t) \simeq 1.42 \cdot 10^{15} \cdot e^{0.507(t-2008)}$$
Why does the expression for $y$ look like this? I have tried to take the expontential function of both sides of $\text{ln }y \simeq 0.507t-983.054$ but I still cannot see why the expression for $y$ looks like that.

Comment: Very good question. However, I am wondering what value is gained by re-writing the   equation in terms of "e"?

Comment: How would you otherwise write the expression for y when you have the expression for ln y?

Comment: you would simply write $y \simeq e^{0.507t-983.054}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that$$1.42\cdot10^{15}\simeq e^{34.8894}$$and that therefore$$1.42\cdot10^{15}\cdot e^{0.507\times(t-2008)}\simeq e^{34.8894-0.507\times2008+0.507t}.$$But $34.8894-0.507\times2008\simeq-983.054$. So$$1.42\cdot10^{15}\cdot e^{0.507\times(t-2008)}\simeq e^{0.507t-983.054}.$$

Comment: Thanks! However, I still do not really get why taking the exponential function of $0.507t-983.054$ should become $1.42 \cdot 10^{15} \cdot e^{0.507(t-2008)}$? You have explained the logic behind the end result but not how taking re-write the expression for ln $y$ to an expression for $y$ - sort of step by step. I hope you understand what I just tried to said :))) Thanks again!

Comment: Please ask if you did not get what I mean :=)))))

Comment: Since $\ln y\simeq0.507t-983.954$, you have that\begin{align}y&\simeq e^{0.507t-983.954}\\&=e^{0.507(t-2008)+0.507\times2008-983.954}\\&=e^{0.507\times2008-983.954}e^{0.507(t-2008)}\\&\simeq1.42\cdot10^{15}e^{0.507(t-2008)}.\end{align}Is it clear now?

Comment: Clever answer indeed. I was wondering if showing the equation in terms of power of $e$ has certain meaning or significance. I get that the $2008$ is the first year on the X-Axis, so it looks like this has a meaning. Thanks.

Comment: The number $t-2008$ is the number of years that have passed since when someone stated to gather data.

Comment: Thank you much.

Comment: @NoChance But yea.. I still do not really get *why* you would write it in the suggested way instead of the more obvious way. In the end, it is the same result

Comment: @npp there must be a reason behind writing it in this way. In regression, you can obtain a function of the form a*e^{bx}, and find a, b from the data, so why go to $ln(x)$ first, then write in in complex exponent form? Not very clear!